# How to configure File Manager plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce, rich-text-editor, file-manager

I'm using tinyMce for textarea, and with this I'm using [File Manager Plugin](http://test.albertoperipolli.com/filemanager4tinymce/) but I haven't had luck with the configuration file.

This is some of the original content

```
$base_url="http://localhost"; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
$upload_dir = '/tinymce/source/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
$current_path = '../../../../source/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
```

What I got is this

```
$base_url="http://localhost/atravesfree";
$upload_dir = '/atravesfree/public/source/';
$current_path = '';
```

And this is the result, I have an image inside the folder but it's not shown. I know I need to set the "current_path" but I don't know how do that exactly.

[image: File Manager Result]

I'm using a framework called "Freekore" and this is how the order of the folders look like

```
This is the location of the filemanager folder
-root [localhost/atravesfree - G:/wamp/www/atravesfree]
    |-public
        |-_HTML
            |-themes
                |-mytheme
                    |-js
                        |-plugins
                            |-filemanager
```

---

```
This is the location where I have, and where I want, the uploaded files
-root [localhost/atravesfree - G:/wamp/www/atravesfree]
    |-public
        |-source
```

Thank you for your help.

---

After I solve this I got this error "the path is not writable", the reason was that the "thumbs" folder didn't have write permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
$dir='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$dir=str_replace('filemanager', '', $dir);
$base_url="http://www.site.com";
$upload_dir = $dir.'source/';
$current_path = '../source/';
$thumbs_base_path = '../thumbs/';
```

obviously replace dir and your site. Thumbs is optional.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this as soon as possible.

Comment: Didn't work, I got this error "There is an error! The root folder not exist."

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles on this like I did,
these settings worked for me

The URL for my project is set up like this
http://127.0.0.1/project/branch/public/

```
$base_url = "";
$upload_dir = "/project/branch/public/path/to/tinymce/upload_dir/";
$current_path = "/../../upload_dir/";
```

make sure you follow setup instructions in their github repo

Answer (score 0):

I have this code in my cakephp 2:

```
$root = rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'/'); // don't touch this configuration        
$root = $root."/cakephp/app/webroot";

    $base_url="http://localhost/cakephp"; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
    $upload_dir = '/tinymce/source/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
    $current_path = '../../../../source/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
```

I have followed this structure:

```
 // root(cakephp/app/webroot)
//   |- tinymce
//   |    |- source <- upload folder
//   |    |- js
//   |    |   |- tinymce
//   |    |   |    |- plugins
//   |    |   |    |-   |- filemanager
//   |    |   |    |-   |-      |- thumbs <- folder of thumbs [must have the write permission]
```

Hope that this helps to other user.